# How do I pass the recordId from Aura to my Apex controller?

Tags: apex, aura, record

I have access to recordId in Aura and I want to access it in my Apex Controller.  I am following the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_pass_data.htm) here.

I keep getting an error that it can't find the serverEcho controller file.  (See doInit js file -> var action = component.get("c.serverEcho");).

But in all the examples in the docs, there is no such file - it is just a reference to the apex controller function's name.  What am I missing?  Thank you.

//.cmp file

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
     <lightning:card title="Lightning Aura Component">
        <div class="slds-p-around_small">
            Current Record ID in Lightning Aura Component: <strong>{!v.recordId}</strong> <br/><br/>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
    <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.demo_salesforce_hello + '/index.html?recordid=' + v.recordId}"
                          onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
</aura:component>
```

//.js file

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        var action = component.get("c.serverEcho");
        action.setParams({ recordId : recordId });
        //adding this doesn't work either nor does adding a callback
        //$A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

//apex controller
global with sharing class ContactController {

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String serverEcho(String recordId) {
    return ('Hello from the server, ' + recordId);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the controller attribute to your **aura:component header** :

Something like this :  `controller="ContactController"`

```
<aura:component controller="ContactController " implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
 <lightning:card title="Lightning Aura Component">
    <div class="slds-p-around_small">
        Current Record ID in Lightning Aura Component: <strong>{!v.recordId}</strong> <br/><br/>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
<lightning:container src="{!$Resource.demo_salesforce_hello + '/index.html?recordid=' + v.recordId}"
                      onerror="{!c.handleError}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately, I still get this error: A Component Error has occured! Error: Unable to find action 'serverEcho' on the controller of c:demo_salesforce_hello Component: c:demo_salesforce_hello . Caused by: Unable to find action 'serverEcho' on the controller of c:demo_salesforce_hello

Comment: @Nour please check again if you correct named  your controller in Aura header. Because the error which you write goes only if you named it incorrect or there no such class or method.

Comment: In other words Nour, swap out ContactController with the name of your Apex class.

Comment: Thank you again, it works!